# Comparing values in Column 2 corresponding to equal values from Column 1 in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, min

I'm writing a code with Python.
My input is a (780, 2) numpy array that has values like this:

```
[100.2 45
 100.5 54
 200.2 62
 100.2 67
 100.5 88
 ...
 ...
 200.2 99]
```

in random order.

I want to compare the values in second column corresponding to equal values in the first column and then create a new array with only the maximum of those.
I'm expecting an output like this:

```
[100.2 67
 100.5 88
 ...
 ...
 200.2 99]
```

The order of the new array doesn't matter to me.

Any help with a code to generate it would be much appreciated!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the minimal code you've tried so far?

Comment: you want pandas solution for same?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, my new data is with three columns now. I used a solution from another question, which worked for two columns, but doesn't work for three. The code was `(df.sort_values(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], ascending=[True, False]).drop_duplicates(['Col1']).reset_index(drop=True))` Is it possible to use a similar approach for three columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input = np.array([[3, 11.1],[13, 22.2],[11, 33.3],[13, 44.4],[3,55.5]])
bbb = input.T
x = np.zeros(int(np.max(bbb[0]))+1)
np.maximum.at(x, np.array(bbb[0],dtype='int'), bbb[1])
np.array([[np.sort(list(set(bbb[0]))),x[np.nonzero(x)]]]).T
```